# How to place text in matplotlib on a line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot text on a 2D line in matplotlib. This is how I define a line:

```
        line = pyplot.Line2D((x1, x2), (y1, y2))
```

What exactly should I write so that I get my text directly on the line (line is not horizontal or vertical, it can be in any direction)? I want to use matplotlib.text.

Comment: Why are you creating `Line2D` objects directly instead of using `ax.plot`?  This is not built in, you will have to do a `ax.text` per letter and sort out what the location + rotation should be based on the normal to your line.

Comment: I found a code on the internet and it had Line2D. It's pretty complex (it draws neural network) and I don't know how to change it to ax.plot. Is it possible to combine ax.plot and Line2D?